# UsageStatsManager returning data from just last day/week/month/year?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to query `UsageStats` from `UsageStatsManager`.
I've build a `DateUtils` class that provide me with methods to get the start and end time of each day/month/year (week is coming), like this:

```
public static Calendar getCal(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal;
}

public static long getDayStart(int year, int month, int day) {
    return getCal(year, month, day).getTimeInMillis();
}

public static long getDayEnd(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar cal = getCal(year, month, day);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

I'm using these longs to query `UsageStats` for different days:

```
 mUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);
```

I can get data for today, but previous days will return an empty list.

This is what I use to get the data:

```
12 nov 2014, with type UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY
startTime: 1415746800000
endTime: 1415833200000
mUsageStats size: 18

11 nov 2014, with type UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY
startTime: 1415660400000
endTime: 1415746800000
mUsageStats size: 0
```

Is there a limit in the API that prevents me from getting older data or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, the API seems limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can get usage stats from whatever date you want (within the bounds set [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager)) by using `queryAndAggregateUsageStats()` method with correct milliseconds like this:

```
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
if(mUsageStatsManager != null){
    Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // get yesterdays data
    Calendar  endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Map<String, UsageStats> queryUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(beginCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```