# Get App usage data of previous dates from UsageStatsManager Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

If I want to get data of today's **App usage**, first I allowed my App from settings to read App usage statistics,
then  I am using this query to get **UsageStats**

```
UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
```

(I am calculating startTimeStamp and endTimeStamp programmatically, but here it is hardcoded as an example).

```
long  startTimeStamp = 1452124800000;           // today's Morning 12:00:00 AM
long  endTimeStamp= 1452211199000;              // today's Night 11:59:59 PM

List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST, startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp);
```

successfully I am getting correct data from **UsageStatsManager**.

But if I use same query to get data of *yesterday's* **App Usage**, I just changed  `startTimeStamp` and `endTimeStamp` values by *yesterday's* TimeStamp values.

I am not getting any data from **UsageStatsManager**. It returns me an empty list.

I have also tried the same query by changing `intervalType` to `UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY`. but still, I am getting empty data from Android UsageStatsManager.

Is there any way to get App usage data of previous day(s) ??

Comment: i think this( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882956/usagestatsmanager-returning-data-from-just-last-day-week-month-year ) thread also have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can get usage stats from whatever date you want (within the bounds discussed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager)) by using `queryAndAggregateUsageStats()` method with correct milliseconds like this:

```
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
if(mUsageStatsManager != null){
    Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Calendar  endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Map<String, UsageStats> queryUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(beginCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```